# Prediction of Adaboost Classifier between 0 and 1

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I have to use an Adaboost classifier to predict if the data is a signal (1) or a background (0) event. But since the output is expected to be 1 or 0 the `model.predict(X)` function gives only 1 or 0 as output. Nevertheless, to further examine the prediction result, we have to use a function which creates a cut-off value for the prediction. Since there are only two possible prediction states, this cut-off value does not make any sense (it simply has to be >0 two separate between signal and background.

Now, is there a way that I can receive an output between 0 and 1?

I tried to use `model.decision_function(X)`, but there the output is between -5 and 1 (and if needed: the ROC-curve looks really good, so it seems as the model works fine).
In the following, I show my implementation, so you know what I do:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

model = AdaBoostClassifier(
        DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4,
                                criterion="entropy",
                                splitter="random",
                                min_samples_split = 2),
        n_estimators=100,
        learning_rate=0.1
        )
#fitting:
model.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
model.predict(Xtest) #creates 0 and 1 output

model.decision_function(Xtest) #creates unusable range between -5 and 1
```

An example histogram of the output of the decision function:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sklearn you have predic_proba(X) function, which should give you the probability i.e output between 0-1

In ada_boost, this will be the weighted average of the probabilities of the classifiers in the ensemble.